# How to approach focus stacking (super resolution) with GetUserMedia() in pure javascript

Tags: javascript, image, focus, resolution, super

I have a use case where I will be capturing a video via GetUserMedia and extracting frames that contain an object.

I would like to take the candidate frames and merge them together to create a sharper image.

I know I can use Blend Mode Differences (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blend_modes#Difference) to see what is different between the frames so they could be aligned but this seems a nieve approach.

Is there a better way to approach this problem? Are you aware of any sample code in Javascript that implements this concept of image/focus stacking to create a sharper image from multiple frames I could learn from?